# life cycle of Android activity

Tags: android

Could you please list and explain all the methods in the lifecycle of an Android activity, including when they are called by the system?

List of lifecycle of an Android activity

In my Android development course, I encountered a question regarding the lifecycle of Android activities. This arose in the context of a session focused on understanding the intricacies of activity management within Android apps. We were discussing how effectively managing activities is crucial for creating stable and efficient applications, and this led to a deeper exploration of the specific methods involved in an activity's lifecycle and when the system triggers each of these methods.

Answer (score 0):

## Android Activity Lifecycle Methods

In the lifecycle of an Android Activity, there are several key methods that are called by the system at specific moments:

1. **`onCreate()`**: This is the first method in the activity lifecycle. It is called when the activity is first created. You should do all normal static set up here: create views, bind data to lists, etc. This method receives a `Bundle` object which contains the state of the activity if it was previously destroyed.
2. **`onStart()`**: Called when the activity becomes visible to the user. If the activity enters the foreground, this will be called just after it.
3. **`onResume()`**: Called when the activity is ready to start interacting with the user. At this point, the activity is at the top of the activity stack and captures all user input. Most of the core functionality is implemented in this method.
4. **`onPause()`**: Called when the system is about to start or resume another activity. This is typically where you commit unsaved changes, stop animations, and other things that may be consuming CPU.
5. **`onStop()`**: Called when the activity is no longer visible to the user. It might be because a new activity is starting, or an existing one is resuming and covering it up. This is typically where resources are released.
6. **`onDestroy()`**: Called just before the activity is destroyed. This can be either because the activity is finishing (someone called `finish()`), or the system is temporarily destroying this instance to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the `isFinishing()` method.
7. **`onRestart()`**: Called when the activity is restarting from a stopped state before it starts back up. This indicates that the activity is being started up again.

Comment: There are two methods almost all subclasses of Activity will implement:
onCreate(Bundle) is where you initialize your activity. Most importantly, here
you will usually call setContentView(int) with a layout resource defining your UI,
and using findViewById(int) to retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to
interact with programmatically.
onPause() is where you deal with the user pausing active interaction with the
activity. Any changes made by the user should at this point be committed
(usually to the ContentProvider holding the data).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if you want to read in more detail then [click](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)